# How do I fix this react memory leak

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, use-effect

Every time I login I get a memory leak error. Unsure how to fix it.... or why it's happening. I tried unmounting but it did not work. I am unsure why it's not working. Any help is appreciated.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVUAv.png]

Comment: return accept a function

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Firebase:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(User => {
        if (User) {
            // your own logic here
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    })
}, [])
```

Try not to save that event (it's an event) on a variable.
Other memory problems could happen if you call a component inside the same component.